# breaking out of browser.actions().mouseMove in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a need for using the actions.mouseMove() fuction to hover over a reactive dropdown element. After doing so and clicking the elemen, that reactive dropdown persists so I now need to find someway to move the mouse away from the hover box. I do this by including a return browser.actions().mouseDown().perform() after I click my link. Here is my full function

```
this.changeCurrentClient = function() {
    var profile = $('[id="hdr-profile-wrapper"]');
    var changeClient = element(by.buttonText('Change Client'));
    browser.actions().mouseMove(profile).perform();
    changeClient.click();
    return browser.actions().mouseDown().perform();
};
```

This works fine, however the problem is that when I run this on the grid, it sometimes does not properly do the moveDown() function to break out of the hover menu. I assume this is because it runs a bit slower on the grid and the DOM takes a bit longer to load. Is there a better way to break out of this rather than refreshing or doing a hard wait?

I have tried implicitly waiting for another element on the page outside of the hover menu before doing the mouseDown(), however it seems like that first action.perform() pretty much isolates you to that hover menu, so no other elements outside of the hover menu can be found. Is a refresh really the only way to do this?

Comment: I have seen issues after using actions(), that spread to even a second window handle (i.e. browser.switchTo().window(winHandles[1]);). Seems there should be a way to stop the action especially if ending with .perform()